# How to pull for all files except one?

Tags: git, git-pull

I want to pull changes except for one file (`GNUmakefile` below). I've looked at the [`git-pull(3)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) man pages, but the option is not readily apprent to me.

How do I pull all changes, but skip the file that's causing git trouble? Is there an option to "ignore files with conflicts" or "ignore file X" or similar?

(The worst part is, the `GNUmakefile` was copied/pasted between virtual machines, so they are nearly the same file. `cryptopp-rw`'s makefile has a few dependency recipes added at the end of it).

```
cryptopp-rw$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 4), reused 4 (delta 4), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
   4206b4a..cf08f3e  master     -> origin/master
Updating 4206b4a..cf08f3e
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    GNUmakefile
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: Stash the file (`git stash`) then put it back the pull with `git stash apply`. Fix any merge conflicts

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff. That's two extra steps in the process. Is there no way to do it in 0 steps (with an option)? I might as well use `mv` from the command line, which does not require me to read a man page or fight with a source control tool.

Comment: `git fetch` (and, by extension, `git pull`) operates on *commits*, not files. It does not have any options pertaining to individual files.

Answer (score 6):

You can stash the current working tree then make a pull, this way will prevent git to throw an error and abort the process. After the pull you can restore the stashed files with:

```
git stash pop stash@{<revision>}
```

Or if this solution needs some extra steps which you want to prevent you can ignore the files which causing troubles by overriding with the files already on git repository:

```
git checkout HEAD^ file/to/overwrite
git pull
```

Or you can try to pull with `-f` command:

```
git pull -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering even [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree) wouldn't prevent `git pull` from updating that one file, you are left with using a workaround like:

- making an alias '`gpu`' calling a script
- making a script which will save that one file elsewhere, do the git pull, overwrite that one file with the saved one (that way, no conflict to resolve from a `stash pop`)